# Nested Loops performance issue on a very simple query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very simple table and a very simple `INNER JOIN` query and a huge count of rows.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#blackIPAndMACs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #blackIPAndMACs
       
CREATE TABLE #blackIPAndMACs
(
       ResourceID     dsidentifier,
       MACAddress     VARCHAR(500),
       IPAddress      VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE INDEX #blackIPAndMACs_idx1 ON #blackIPAndMACs(MACAddress)
CREATE INDEX #blackIPAndMACs_idx2 ON #blackIPAndMACs(IPAddress)
CREATE INDEX #blackIPAndMACs_idx3 ON #blackIPAndMACs(MACAddress, IPAddress)
CREATE INDEX #blackIPAndMACs_idx4 ON #blackIPAndMACs(ResourceID)
```

After this table has been filled with 2.514.000 rows, I am trying to find all ResourceID, that accessed from similar IP or MAC:

```
SELECT b1.*,
       b2.*
FROM   #blackIPAndMACs b1 with(NOLOCK, INDEX=#blackIPAndMACs_idx3) 
       INNER JOIN #blackIPAndMACs b2 with(NOLOCK, INDEX=#blackIPAndMACs_idx3)
            ON  (
                    b1.MACAddress = b2.MACAddress
                    OR b1.IPAddress = b2.IPAddress
                )    
WHERE  1 = 1
```

As a result, this query executes (possible) infinitely. Our server is **really** powerful. I think I can't disclose this information, but I can only say, that the RAM of the server counts in a lot of hundreds of GB.

[image]

What kind optimization should I use to speedup the query execution?

**Update 1:**

OK, I removed `OR` and changed `SELECT` to `count (b1.ResourceID)`, but it didn't solve the issue. Even such simple query executes too long:

```
SELECT count (b1.ResourceID)
FROM   #blackIPAndMACs b1 with(NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN #blackIPAndMACs b2 with(NOLOCK)              
                    b1.MACAddress = b2.MACAddress
WHERE  1 = 1
AND b1.ResourceID != b2.ResourceID
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't you join on the ResourceID (or something else, like timestamp) not being the same, so you don't pointlessly join every record to itself, instead of finding similar-but-not-identical rows? (or join on only one `xor` the other of IP and MAC being the same, or whatever else)

Comment: Why are you creating four indices when you are forcing sql server to use one? Those query hints should be used as a last resort.

Comment: I would steer clear of using `(NOLOCK)`

Comment: ResourceID will not be same. I just simplified query, but originally this query is more complex. Each of #blackIPAndMACs (b1 and b2) joins to another table (lets name it Owners - o1 and o2) by ResourceID and, after that, there is `where` clause, where o1.OwnerId!=o2.OwnerId.

Comment: I understand that you've simplified your query, but we are not able to gauge what your problem is when you don't post your whole problem query?

Comment: Anyway, if to don't simplify it, the problem persists. OKay, I added `where` clause `b1.ResourceID!=b2.ResourceID`, but 87% of Nested Loops is still in Execution plan...

Comment: The lack of a unique key and clustered index is suspect. For the query, consider using separate `SELECT` statements combined with `UNION` instead of the `OR` join criteria.

Answer (score 2):

As a force of habit I would refrain from using `select *`, even if you need a whole bunch of fields as a result. Having said that my approach would be something like this:

```
SELECT
          b1.ResourceID
        , b2.MACAddress
        , b2.IPAddress
        , b3.MACAddress
        , b3.IPAddress
FROM      #blackIPAndMACs AS b1
LEFT JOIN #blackIPAndMACs AS b2 ON b1.MACAddress = b2.MACAddress
LEFT JOIN #blackIPAndMACs AS b3 ON b1.IPAddress = b2.IPAddress;
```

Which uses a much more efficient query plan:

[image]

Comment: I agree with the `select *`, upvote from me as it looks like this query would be a sufficient solution.

Comment: You can't assume your query plan will be the same as the OP though, as it can be dependent on the statistics on the table. You also have a possible cross join here that might multiply the number of rows returned. EG if there are two rows that satisfy both Mac and IP address, you will get 4 rows in result set.